# cabal install hsdev fails with ExitFailure 1

Tags: haskell, cabal-install, hsdev

I was trying to setup Haskell auto completion on Sublime text on macOS Sierra using the pligin SublimeHaskell that requires the package hsdev. So when I try to install hsdev using cabal version `2.0.0.2` on ghci version `8.2.1` I get the following error-

```
Building regex-pcre-builtin-0.94.4.8.8.35...
Failed to install regex-pcre-builtin-0.94.4.8.8.35
Build log ( /Users/harpreet/.cabal/logs/ghc-8.2.1/regex-pcre-builtin-0.94.4.8.8.35-ErSIfFBjU2O890llA9JKT4.log ):
cabal: Entering directory '/var/folders/q3/0p0mxly93xv0khxhp59n7qrc0000gn/T/cabal-tmp-17197/regex-pcre-builtin-0.94.4.8.8.35'
Configuring regex-pcre-builtin-0.94.4.8.8.35...
Preprocessing library for regex-pcre-builtin-0.94.4.8.8.35..
Building library for regex-pcre-builtin-0.94.4.8.8.35..
<command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id regex-base-0.93.2-6R4SyH615Fd96n1BuXT5nY:
    regex-base-0.93.2-6R4SyH615Fd96n1BuXT5nY is unusable due to shadowed dependencies:
      mtl-2.2.1-19EL8AGBsN3DnnOhrC9xY3
    (use -v for more information)
```

and finally the build fails with the message -

```
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
hsdev-0.2.5.1-KLZyINgHjNjLoIhf1REoIt depends on hsdev-0.2.5.1 which failed to
install.
regex-pcre-builtin-0.94.4.8.8.35-ErSIfFBjU2O890llA9JKT4 failed during the
building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

How should I fix this?

Comment: Use stack to install `hsdev`.

Comment: You should look at the log file for clues as to why it happens. I guess trying  every conceivable way of building the package is one potential solution - maybe one will work!

Comment: This was likely a problem with haskell platform builds. cf: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46599487/371753